# Empty an array before push

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I took back a project using Angularjs. There is a filtering system.
Actually, a click on a category **add** this category to a list. All industries that got the category are shown. Note that a click on an already selected category remove this category.

I would like a click to **replace** the filtering category so that each click do not add the category. How should I modify this code:

```
$scope.changerCategorie = function(category , name ){
    if( jQuery.inArray(category, $scope.selected ) !== -1)
    {
       angular.forEach($scope.selected , function(obj,index){

            if( category == obj ){
                $scope.selected.splice(index,1);
                $scope.selected_name.splice(index,1);
            }
       });

    }else{
        $scope.selected.push(category);
        $scope.selected_name.push(name);
    }
    $scope.selected_filter = $scope.selected.join(', ');

}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
$scope.changerCategorie = function(category , name ){

      $scope.selected = 0;
      $scope.selected_name = 0;

      $scope.selected = category;
      $scope.selected_name = name;

      $scope.selected_filter = $scope.selected.join(', ');

}
```

and I get

```
$scope.selected.join is not a function
```

If I remove the line related to selected.join I got another error after two clicks:

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: tags in selected_name, Duplicate key: string:l
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the preferred way to empty an array in javascript is to set its length to 0: `$scope.selected.length = 0`.

The reason you are getting an error on join() is that you are now setting `$scope.selected` directly to the category, which is not an array. This would fix that:
`$scope.selected = [category];`

Of course, you only need one of these methods. Either an empty followed by a push, or the direct assignment. Also if you are planning on completely getting rid of the multiple filter feature, it may be better in the long run to store it as just a category rather than an array.